# Appropriate for YA?

Tags: fiction

Is it okay to have cussing, sex, drug use, rape, and brutal violence in a young adult novel?  Can you give examples of published YA novels that have these things in them?

Comment: Appropriate? As far as I can tell, today it is pretty much required.

Answer (score 3):

It is a misconception of laypeople that certain topics are not (a necessary) part of the lives of children or teenagers. The truth is, that minors of all ages try very hard to come to terms with the most difficult aspects of life. They consider death and pain and sexuality and what it means for them, and they think about this much harder than adults usually do, who have found their answers and have settled into their truths. Childhood and adolescence are about understanding yourself, the world, and life, and everything that entails.

What is different about children, adolescents, and adults, is that adults "can take it" (or know how to avoid it), while a certain way of dealing with difficlt topics can negatively affect younger people, especially if they are unprepared. You don't want to show a video of a forced gangbang to an kindergarten age child asking about where babies come from, but you can – and should, many people think – warn the same child not to get into a car with a stranger, and you should even explain the danger in an age appropriate manner, so the child doesn't remain baffled and confused but know how to judge new situations correctly. You won't go into the details of sexual child abuse, but you will explain to them, that a stranger might touch them in an inappropriate manner and against their will, that is you will discuss the matter of consense and the privacy of the body.

Now if you go to a bookstore and look a the section with childrens' books, you may (depending on the bookstore) find books that deal with just this topic. There are picture books in which children narrowly escape pedophile predators and the danger that they were in is explained to them. That is, there are fiction books for rather young children about pedophilia and sexual child abuse.

Adolescents know more than children, understand more, and want to be given more detail. They are at an age where they engage in sexual activities, and it would be extremely strange if you avoided that topic. Teenagers have sex. At about 17 (depending on country) about half of all kids have had sex, and the rest follows soon enough. So you don't have to beat around the bush. And teens know all those words, too, (and have most of them seen the respective body parts in action on the internet), so if you cannot deal with these topics *like an adult*, then you quickly lose the respect of your audience.

On the other hand, books for teenagers are not porn. Sexuality in a YA novel should not exist solely for the sake of arousing its readers. Yes, you can show how sex is erotic and your readers may certainly become aroused, but the sex (and the way you describe it) should serve a purpose within the story you want to tell. If the graphic details are unimportant, leave them out. But if the protagonist wonders whether he should shave his pubic hair before his first date and then googles and finds porn and later cuts himself, then by all means describe all that goes through that person's head (and eyes) in the necessary detail.

The same, of course, goes for other taboo topics like drugs or violence. Many teens (and even children) experience or witness them, and it is necessary for them to think about them, so if you feel up to the topic, deal with them. But again, don't have your character cuss and curse because *you* like that. They only should do it because it is who they are, and you should only have them do it as much as is necessary for your readers to understand who they are.

In the end, as a writer of books for minors, you have a responsibility. If you want to express yourself and not restrict your self expression, you might be more of an adult writer (even if you happen to be underage yourself). If you write for children or adolescents, there must be some underlying sense of care in your book. Show how life can hurt people, but do not inflict pain through your writing. You can do that, if you write for adults.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is it depends on how they are dealt with. Teenagers will read about all these things quite happily. Parents, librarians and even education authorities will ban them or get very upset about students reading them.

For example, I remember 'The Chocolate War' by Robert Cormier being banned in NSW because it had a boy masturbating. 'Forever' by Judy Blume was banned because of the sex. A poem was removed from the AQA GCSE anthology because of the suggested (not even described) violence. 'The Lesson' a poem about teachers killing children was banned after the Dunblane massacre. However, 'Maggot Moon' won a children's book award. 'Heroes' by Robert Cormier, which deals with sexual abuse of children, is a popular novel in schools.